# What is the rationale for the third rule of the follow set algorithm?

Tags: compiler-construction, ll-grammar

For a compilers class, we were presented with the following rules for finding the FOLLOW(A):

α

1. If A is the start symbol, add '$' to FOLLOW(A)
2. If A -> α B β, add FIRST(β) - {ε} to FOLLOW(B)
3. If A -> α B, or ( A -> α B β and β *-> [image] ), add FOLLOW(A) to FOLLOW(B).

We were also given the informal definition of the Follow(A):
The set of terminals which can immediately follow A in a sentential form.

Why is the third rule true?

I understand how to apply the third rule, but I'm confused about why it must be the case.  Could anyone provide a concrete example that requires its use, or an example which would fail the informal definition in absence of the third rule?

Comment: I think this question might be off topic here and you'll have much better luck on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Rob when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat Yes. I know. And usually mention it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you have a production rule

> A → αBβ

and you know that β can derive the empty string. In that case, a character that can legally follow the A nonterminal can also follow the B nonterminal if you used the above production rule and then expanded β to the empty string.

As an example, let’s look at this simple grammar:

> S → Ax
>
> A → CBC
>
> C → ε
>
> B → y

Here, we can do this derivation that puts an x after B:

> S → Ax → CBCx → CBx